# Error on create email send definiton

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I got following error on create email send definiton. Please suggest me what the cause of this and how resolve it.

> StatusCode: 'Error',
>          StatusMessage: 'RequestID: 2eaa87f7-5e89-4a10-bd77-e1afb4489ffd Message: MemberID 72XXXXX does not have access to ClientID[62XXXX]
>   PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] CustomerKey[] supplied in
>   the Client object',
>          OrdinalID: '0',
>          ErrorCode: '2',
>          NewID: '0',
>          Object: [Object] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account you are using does not have permissions to use the api. Get your system admin to grant those privileges to it